# How can i scrape Aliexpress product data

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape Aliexpress product data of a [product page](https://es.aliexpress.com/item/32601027783.html?spm=a2g01.12597576.p99adbb.14.446648cbwGcCAc&gps-id=7316167&scm=1007.19881.118560.0&scm_id=1007.19881.118560.0&scm-url=1007.19881.118560.0&pvid=c54c44bc-a2d0-4302-8619-a72b3e5bf841) with Python and BeautifulSoup.

I run the next code making reference to an YML file (aliexpress.yml) with Aliexpress CSS selectors created with SelectorLib:

```
from selectorlib import Extractor
import requests
import json
import argparse

argparser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
argparser.add_argument('url', help='Amazon Product Details URL')
# Create an Extractor by reading from the YAML file
e = Extractor.from_yaml_file('./aliexpress.yml')

user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.246'
headers = {'User-Agent': user_agent}
# Download the page using requests
args = argparser.parse_args()
r = requests.get(args.url, headers=headers)
# Pass the HTML of the page and create
data = e.extract(r.text)
# Print the data
print(json.dumps(data, indent=True))
```

I receive the next response:

```
{
 "name": null,
 "price": null,
 "image": null
}
```

I have other YML files for Amazon and other ecommerce and works properly, but with Aliexpress it returns null. Is strange because in SelectorLib i can view the preview data correctly, so the YML file is correct.

Could be Aliexpress blocking my scraping? How i can scrape Aliexpress data without null response?

Comment: Have you checked the content of `r.text`?

Comment: How does `Extractor` parse the data?

Comment: Why scrape their HTML when they [publish an API](https://developers.aliexpress.com/en/doc.htm?docId=108970&docType=1)?

Comment: @HristoIliev i checked the r.text seems that the css selectors that i'm looking for not appear there. Why not appear?, when i inspect the aliexpress link, the css selectors could be identified.

Comment: Perhaps the web page is created dynamically using JavaScript. Have you looked at the page source? There is a huge chunk of JavaScript containing a lot of data and possibly everything you need to scrape from the page. Also, use their API.

Comment: @AndrésMangasJiménez check below answer

Comment: Thanks for the explanation guys.

Comment: Doesn't their API require business license?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Page is loaded via `JavaScript`, So `requests` will not help you to render the `JS`. you can use `selenium` or whatever modules which render `JS`.
2. I noticed that your desired data is located within `script` tag, which you can actually `loads` it within `JSON` and then `parse` it.
3. The reason why you are able to see the `elements` within the `inspect element` of your driver because the browser is actually visualize it for you, But if you checked the `page source`, you will notice it's not located with it if you disabled the `JS`.

Here I've loaded the `script` within `JSON`, you can access it as `JSON` `dict`

```py
import requests
import json
import re

target = ["title", "itemDetailUrl", "imagePath"]


def main(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    match = re.search(r'data: ({.+})', r.text).group(1)
    data = json.loads(match)
    goal = [data['pageModule'][x] for x in target] + \
        [data['priceModule']['formatedActivityPrice']]
    print(goal)


main("https://es.aliexpress.com/item/32601027783.html")
```

Output:

```
['Nueva versión Xiaomi Mi cargador de coche Dual USB versión de carga rápida 37W Max con puntas de luz LED para iPhone Huawei Xiaomi para Samsung|charger dual|dual usb|mi car - AliExpress', 
'https://es.aliexpress.com/item/32601027783.html', 
'https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/H6f0b93e98bb646d5a1183161b65707e3P/Nueva-versi-n-Xiaomi-Mi-cargador-de-coche-Dual-USB-versi-n-de-carga-r-pida.jpg', 
'€ 9,31 - 10,86']
```

Comment: Thank you very much, seems that it is the way ;)

Comment: JS still uses REST API nodes cant we patch into those?